# How do electrons escape nuclear reactors to cause Cherenkov radiation?

Tags: radiation, gamma-rays, cherenkov-radiation

From what I understand, nuclear reactor cores are shielded, so that gamma rays don't get too far too often. But since electrons are expected to penetrate less material, then how are underwater nuclear reactors glowing blue?

This would mean that not only are charged particles like electrons travelling at near the speed of light, but that there are even more gamma rays in the nearby space, both originating from the fission reactions. Are these levels of radiation considered safe?

Comment: "Are these levels of radiation considered safe?"  thats what all those tons of water are for, to make it safe,

Comment: The water is the shield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pool type reactors, a large volume of water is used to shield the radiation (neutrons, gammas, betas) coming from the immersed fuel rods.  The volume must be large enough to block the gammas and moderate the neutrons to safe levels outside the pool.  Even though betas may not go as far in the water as other particles (characteristic path lengths of all these particles will depend on their energy), they still create Cerenkov radiation that is visible.  Note the water can also serve as a coolant for the reactor.